# Need to use 0.8.2 with streaming plugin but gephi can't find catalog

Tags: gremlin, gephi

I'm trying out streaming connection between Tinkerpop (3.1.1-incubating) gremlin and Gephi using the streaming plugin as it's outlined in Tinkerpop docs.

With 0.9.1 the gremlin plugin seems to send data but nothing renders.

When I looked at the Gephi Streaming plugin, it was meant to work with 0.8.2.  So I uninstalled 0.9.1 and installed 0.8.2.  HOWEVER, now I can't connect to the plugin catalog at https://gephi.org/updates/official/0.8.2/catalog.xml.  I don't have a proxy...  And when I navigate to this catalog.xml in browser, I don't see streaming gephi plugin.

So I downloaded the streaming plugin zip file and tried to install it as zip file - but nothing happens.  There is nothing in the log about any failures with install from zip.

- Thoughts on fixing the zip file install?
- How can I get updates working in 0.8.2 again ?

OR ALTERNATIVELY
 - How do I debug 0.9.1 streaming ?

Thanks,
S-

Comment: OK - after playing around with colors, I do see the graph in Gephi.  Also in the context pane, I do see the 6 nodes and 6 edges being sent.  However they appear to be all smushed into each other in linear layout. Will learn visualization to see if I can get it better.

Thanks for "listening"

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the downloaded streaming zip file had 1/2 dozen nbm's and I needed to install them.  Thanks to Dylan in ThinkAurelius group.  I did that and streaming works.

Steps are:

1. Unzip the graphstreaming.zip into a separate folder
2. This should yield 6 nbm files -- see image: [image: Unzipped file list]
3. Go to Gephi Tools -> Plugins
4. Click the Downloaded Tab
5. Click Add Plugins
6. Navigate to the unzipped folder
7. Select all the nbm's
8. Next select all of the Plugins in the Plugins dialog box
9. Click "Install" -- bottom left of the plugin pane...
10. Restart Gephi when prompted

That installed the Streaming plugin for 0.8.2 and then Gremlin worked and properly showed the graph.

BTW: streaming with 0.9.1 has weird layout rendering in Window10 (but that's for another day)